# iOS Music Controls as Arbitrary Input

Tags: ios, rules

I'm reading how to handle the events themselves, and I know I could intercept them and use them for my own design, but would Apple allow an app like that into the AppStore?

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/RemoteControl/RemoteControl.html

You could imagine playing a game and giving the option of physical back/forward buttons mapped to left/right in your game. I mean to use them when the app is active in the foreground, nothing outside the app or in the software control tray.

This article doesn't say specifically that it's not allowed, but it does imply that the events are to control music only.

Can anyone with more Apple/iOS background refer me to a document which specifies the rules about using the buttons?